# SQLAlchemy Ordering List Insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationships

I'm working on rearranging items in a SQLAlchemy ordering list. It works when I'm moving an item forward eg. position index 1 to 5. But does not work when moving from 5 to 1.

```
### DB MODELS
from_brief_position = self.request.dbsession.query\  
(BriefPosition).filter_by(brief_id=from_brief_id).one()

to_brief_position = self.request.dbsession.query\ 
(BriefPosition).filter_by(brief_id=to_brief_id).one()


### INDEX
from_position = from_brief_position.position.index
to_position = to_brief_position.position.index

### INSERT AND REARRANGE
p = from_brief_position.position
book.indexed_content.insert(to_position, p)
book.indexed_content.reorder()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `to_position` from the list **before** re-inserting it, then perform the `reorder`.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines are the issue:

```
p = from_brief_position.position
book.indexed_content.insert(to_position, p)
```

The second parameter to `insert()` expects an ORM object but you are passing in an integer.